# What is the equivalent of a Java ArrayList<E> in Golang?

Tags: java, arraylist, go

In my particular use case, I would like to know how the following Java code would be implemented in Go -

```
class Channel {
    public String name;
    public Channel(){}
}

ArrayList<Channel> channels = new ArrayList<Channel>();
```

I've gotten started, and I think this would be the appropriate struct for Channel  in Go -

```
struct Channel {
    name string
}
```

I just need to know how ArrayList would work in Go

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use a slice:

```
var channels []Channel  // an empty list
channels = append(channels, Channel{name:"some channel name"})
```

Also, your Channel declaration is slightly off, you need the 'type' keyword:

```
type Channel struct {
    name string
}
```

Here's a complete example: http://play.golang.org/p/HnQ30wOftb

For more info, see the [slices article](http://golang.org/doc/articles/slices_usage_and_internals.html).

There's also the go tour (tour.golang.org) and the language spec (golang.org/ref/spec, see #Slice_types, #Slices, and #Appending_and_copying_slices).

Comment: Thanks, what is the opposite of the append function (e.g. to remove an element)?

Comment: `a = append(a[:i], a[i+1:]...)`

Comment: if all you want to do is remove one from the front or the end then it's even easier: a = a[1:] or a = a[:len(a) - 2] Mostafa's allows you to remove one from the middle of the slice. The best part is that append will in these cases not even have to resize the slice so it's just an in place modification.

Comment: Element removal can be constant time if you don't care about the order of your list. Take the element from the end, copy it to the element index you want removed, and then decrease the slice length by 1.

Comment: See also the ["Slice Tricks" wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks).

Comment: Does append() in golang run on amortized constant time like ArrayList.add() ?

Comment: @Pinch a little bit late but yes it does. you can check that by appending multiple times and noticing the value of cap(s) where s is your slice

Answer (score 1):

Use slices.

For details on common slice idioms see [the "Slice Tricks" wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks).